# How to evaluate Angular 4 expressions without using a template

Tags: angular, dynamic-compilation

I have an application that stores document templates in a database. The document templates contain Angular interpolation expressions and are compiled dynamically against appropriate models to give a preview of the document in an application view. This part works fine.

Now I need to pass the same content to an API method that will generate a Word document. To do this, I will retrieve the template, I will bind it to relevant data, and pass the result to the API. No views or Angular templates need to be involved.

Rougly speaking, I'm looking for an equivalent to the Angular 1.x `$scope.eval()` method. How do I do this in Angular 4?

Comment: if template stored in db are html .. can you use [innerHtml] ?

Comment: They are plain text - with expressions. Using [innerHTML] would mean using a template, which I'm trying not to do, as it seems hacky in the context of what I'm doing.

Comment: ok ..sorry i dind't understood well your question ..so sorry

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion in any case!

Comment: there seems to be no way to do this, to understand why read [this](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) and [this](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)